# How can i open the Walmart website (www.walmart.com.br) inside a frame or an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frame

Someone knows how can i open the website www.walmart.com.br inside a frame or an iframe?

Everytime i call this URL the website opens in full size.

Thats my code:

```
    <FRAMESET ROWS="50%,*" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0">
        <FRAME SRC="http://www.my-web-site-url.com/" NAME="superior" NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO">
        <FRAME SRC="http://www.walmart.com.br" NAME="central" NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO">
    </FRAMESET>
```

I used too:

```
<base target="_self" />
```

Comment: Some websites do not allow themselves to be opened inside an IFrame.

Comment: I suspect they are using some sort of script to break out of your frame: http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/framebreak.shtml

Comment: The website is using what is usually called a frame buster which prevents the website from being opened in an iFrame. they're usually pretty difficult to get around since you have no access to the iframe.

Comment: why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: Robert is correct. Example security risk: Website designer creates bunkofamerica.com, embeds bankofamerica.com, then has malicious Javascript code watch as the user enters their online banking password. There are other ways browsers protect against this, but most secure institutions will have "frame blockers" just as an added precaution.

Comment: just sandbox the iframe to prevent walmart's JS from executing and breaking the frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely NOT good edict, but you can do it with a ruby cgi script using the gems, open-uri, mechanize, nokogiri and cgi. (some gems mentioned are subjective to your goal)

By using nokogiri and open-uri or mechanize, you can download the whole page and open it with a cgi script via gem 'cgi'

It is possible if walmart checks for the HTTP referer value that you wont be able to use iframes.

Using ruby is really a walk around but can be done.. As long as you NEED this functionality on your website.

```
#!/home/pi/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ruby

require 'nokogiri' 
require 'open-uri' 
require 'cgi' 
cgi = CGI.new 
puts cgi.header

puts Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.walmart.com.br"))
```

Note that some pictures or links wont work because they are coded to work on walmarts servers. example, A link on a server would go to "/electronics" well since you're downloading the page and displaying it as if it were on your server you would have to think of a way to add the "http://www.walmart.com.br/" sting for every link.

Comment: Whats the point of giving a ruby example ? Here's some PHP for fun (note i don't do php) ``<% echo implode('', file('http://www.walmart.com.br')) %>``

Comment: And some .NET for fun ``<%= new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.walmart.com.br") %>``

Comment: I would like having more control with ruby.. Depending on this guy wants to do, options are always nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to work fine on http://jsfiddle.net/sLU2Y/

```
<iframe src="http://www.walmart.com.br" height="200" width="200"></iframe>
```

Gives an error of

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'pathname'  

if (!name) name = top.location.pathname;
```

Seems like they could not break out

Otherise like @dandavis said, have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/